# knockout.js bind bootstrap btn-group

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wondering if it's possible to bind the selected value in a Twitter bootstrap radio btn-group to an observable in knockout.js?

In my case, I'm binding the group to an observableArray like so

```
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio" data-bind="foreach: myItemTypes">
    <button class="btn active" data-bind="html: Value, Id: Key">${ Description }</button>
  </div>
```

Any guidance?

Cheers,

Fergal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an example of how this could be done:

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/vu8pk/

By using the css binding we can dynamically turn the "active" class on/off based on the selected observable for each button.

Comment: I love this John. You're coming at the problem from an angle I just never saw. So simple!

Comment: Fiddle is broken (Knockout JS reference returns 404). Here's a fixed version using Microsoft CDN: http://jsfiddle.net/vu8pk/124/

Answer (score 7):

See also [checkedButtons bindingHandler](http://jsfiddle.net/cuhuak/Rswbk/)